# AWS Reducing RDS Instance size causes job to run longer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I recently reduced the size of one of our RDS instances from an `r3.xlarge` to an `r3.large`. Under usual load this is absolutely fine for this instance. We do however have a morning job that runs that is very IO intensive.

Strangely, since reducing the size of the instance we have seen disck IO and cpu utilization consistently lower than before.

I expected to see these metrics increase as we were running the same load with reduced hardware specs?

The most noticeable impact of this is that we have a job that previously completed in ~2 hours now running up to 9 hours+. Of course, I expected it to run slower, but not this exponential when it seems to be now under utilizing the resources available to it?

Does anyone have any ideas why this behaviour would manifest?

Many Thanks,

Comment: How are you measuring IO?  Absolute IOPS, or percentage-utilisation, and how?

Comment: Hi, Looking at the Monitoring graphs in the AWS console for Read Ops per/s and Write Ops per/s

Comment: So, what you're saying is that you have an IO-heavy job, you move it to a smaller system, it then manages less R/W IO operations per second, the job takes longer to complete, and you're surprised?

Comment: Basically yes, but my question was, how has the change in system I have made affected IOPS. All I have done is effectively reduce the memory and cpu, not change the disk at all, so it should be capable of the same iops, should it not? At least up to the limit of the disk, as the cpu is barely being utilized so the bottleneck is the disk still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the table on this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-ec2-config.html) makes clear, Amazon do throttle both absolute throughput to the EBS subsystem, and the number of IOPS an instance may make to it.  They don't list every possible size of instance, but they list enough that it's clear that smaller VMs have less IO capacity available to them.

It is therefore unsurprising that when you moved an IO-limited job to a smaller VM, it took more time to complete.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this article specifically refers to EC2 instances and not RDS instances. I could not find any documentation that mentioned how reducing the instance size of an RDS instance would impact the throughput to EBS?

Comment: The thrust of my answer is that Amazon clearly throttle bandwidth as product size changes.  I am looking at documentation that spells out how RDS backed by SSD storage is also limited in terms of throughput (there's a chunk of up-front throughput allowed, then after that it's at 3 IOPS per GB of allocated storage).  I see no reason to think that **all** their storage isn't throttled in the same way; do you?

Comment: Looking at all the facts it would appear that you are correct. I would argue that it is not very well illustrated in AWS developer docs that this throttling occurs at smaller instance sizes, but like you say, it does make sense. Thanks for your help, I will look at changing the instance type to one that is EBS optimized or look at the cost offset of PIOPS.